# Reduce / Limit number of alerts occurring from Snort Rule Trigger (Syn Flood)

Tags: snort, denial-of-service, intrusion-detection

So I have a snort rule that detects syn flood attacks that looks like this:

> alert tcp any any -> $HOME_NET 80 (msg:”SYN Flood - SSH"; flags:S;
>   flow: stateless; detection_filter: track by_dst, count 40, seconds 10;
>   GID:1; sid:10000002; rev:001; classtype:attempted-dos;)

The problem is, when I trigger it using tcpreplay (With a Ddos.pcapng file):

> sudo tcpreplay -i *interface* */home/Practicak/DDoS.pcapng*

When listening on my VM1, and after running the TCP replay, I get a lot of alerts.. E.G. 100s of Syn Flood Detected alerts.

How can I limit this so that I only get few / 1 alert for each Syn Flood that is initiated? I.E. using the TCPReplay with the pcap file.. & is this good practice to display less alerts?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

@Liam, 
The creation of a threshold would be one answer.
Ref: http://manual-snort-org.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/node35.html

Another would be to do aggregating in the primary data store in which your alert logging is feeding into, for example Elasticsearch or Splunk.